# Swift Radio Buttons Not Clickable

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am using the `DLRadioButton` library through `Cocoa Pods` found [here](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton)

Below is my code, essentially the radio buttons appear however I am only able to click 1 of them in the group and I am unsure why. Note that I am populating the Radio Buttons based on an `Int` in `Firebase` that indicates how many to populate:

```
`   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    pollRef = ref.child("Polls").child(pass)
    passLabel.text = pass
    pollImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: passedImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "test"))

    pollRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.numberOfChildren = Int(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").childrenCount)
    self.passLabel.text = String(self.numberOfChildren)
    print(self.numberOfChildren)

    var buttons = [DLRadioButton]()

    for x in 0..<self.numberOfChildren {
    let answerLabel = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: 
    "answers").childSnapshot(forPath: 
     String(x+1)).childSnapshot(forPath: "answer").value
    let firstRadioButton = self.createRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 
     CGFloat(x)*32, y:self.view.center.y , width: 40.0, height: 20.0), 
     title:  answerLabel as! String, color: UIColor.black)
    //        firstRadioButton.translatesAutore sizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    firstRadioButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: screenSize.height * 0.2)
            firstRadioButton.tag = x
            buttons.append(firstRadioButton)
            self.view.addSubview(firstRadioButton);
        }


    let groupButtons = DLRadioButton()
    groupButtons.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(groupButtons)
    let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide
    groupButtons.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    groupButtons.otherButtons = buttons
    })



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func createRadioButton(frame : CGRect, title : String, color : UIColor) -> DLRadioButton {
    let radioButton = DLRadioButton(frame: frame);
    radioButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14);
    radioButton.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal);
    radioButton.setTitleColor(color, for: UIControlState.normal);
    radioButton.iconColor = color;
    radioButton.indicatorColor = color;
    radioButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.left;
    radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.logSelectedButton(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside);
    return radioButton;
}

@IBAction func logSelectedButton(_ radioButton: DLRadioButton) {
    if radioButton.isMultipleSelectionEnabled {
        for button: DLRadioButton in radioButton.selected() {
            print("\(button.titleLabel?.text) is selected.\n")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("\(radioButton.selected()?.titleLabel?.text) is selected.\n")
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You need to selector method of button

```
let firstRadioButton = self.createRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x, y: CGFloat(x)*32, width: 100.0, height: 120.0), title: answerLabel as! String, color: UIColor.green)
firstRadioButton.tag = x
firstRadioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.logSelectedButton), for: .touchUpInside)
buttons.append(firstRadioButton)
```

**Selector method : you can change as per needs**

```
@IBAction func logSelectedButton(_ radioButton: DLRadioButton) {
        if radioButton.isMultipleSelectionEnabled {
            for button: DLRadioButton in radioButton.selectedButtons {
                print("\(button.titleLabel?.text) is selected.\n")
            }
        }
        else {
            print("\(radioButton.selectedButton.titleLabel?.text) is selected.\n")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am getting the error "Type DLRadioButton does not conform to protocol type "Sequence." I would post the image but StackOverflow is having issues with Imgur apparently.

Comment: if added protocol in interface : UIviewcontroller, sequeceDelegate.....then you need to add it required delegate method in class.